# Display the mouse over values from a pie chart outside the chart in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I want to display the values that are currently displayed on top of the chart on mouseover, outside the chart instead.

I tried to dig further into the dc.js file, but couldn't figure out where the values are being displayed.

Can anyone suggest which function is being called internally inside dc.js?

Comment: The mouseover tooltips use the `<title>` tag, so there isn't really a code path that you can hook into. However, you can add your own `mouseover` event to implement this. I've linked to a previous question. The main difference is that you will select `g.pie-slice` instead of `circle.dot` in order to register your event handler, [as documented in the wiki](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/Chart-selectors).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your response! It worked for me. My code mentioned below:

I added this span inside the section for Gender div:

> 

Used mouse over event with renderlet event:

> .on('renderlet', function(genderTypeChart) {
>          genderTypeChart.selectAll('g.pie-slice')
>              .on('mouseover', function(d) {
>                  genderTypeChart.select('.display-gender').text(d.data.value);
>              })
>              .on('mouseout', function(d) {
>                  genderTypeChart.select('.display-gender').text('');
>              });
>      });